# Best practices to automate mobile apps on non-jailbreak device using SeeTest

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, seetest

I am currently working on planning a test strategy for test automation for our mobile apps.
The problem is that all the automation frameworks I've seen utilize a slightly different context than what the application really uses.

For example, I am evaluating [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/). 
To run automation tests on an non-jailbreak device the developer needs to add some frameworks to the project and actually build a different app the release app. 
So, when testing an instrumented iOS app with SeeTest, the app under test is not the same as the released app, which means that a full regression should be made on the released build.

This is the same of every framework I have seen.

How did others solve this issues?

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a highly-respected mobile development shop for 6 years.  We did not trust automation or emulators as acceptable tools to finalize a build.  Each build was manually tested on the actual handset it was targeted for before the build was sent to the customer.

That's the problem with mobile development.  Unless you find a framework that will run automation using the actual device, you won't have 100% confidence in your build, as you will never really test the deliverable build.

Comment: Both Android and iOS have automation frame work that runs on the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking iOS, you should look into the automated testing support supplied by apple in their tool called instruments.

Comment: I know about instruments and iOS automation FW. Android also has such FW. The problem is that both tests in a slightly different context then the real world. it is like the schrodinger's cat paradox...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Device Anywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/) and [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/)?  They are both services for testing against real devices.  A warning: These aren't cheap solutions.